# Envoyer deployment of upgraded Laravel 5.6 fails quoting mismatched PHP versions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, envoyer.io

I've just updated from Laravel 5.2 to 5.6, with all the various composer updated that are required, but my latest Envoyer deployments are failing in the Instal Composer Dependencies stage.

I get the following error message

> Using Composer archive in source control. Running Command: php
>   composer.phar install --no-interaction --prefer-dist Loading composer
>   repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including
>   require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable
>   set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 2
>       - Installation request for laravel/passport ^7.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v7.2.0].
>       - laravel/passport v7.2.0 requires php >=7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> Problem 3
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.38 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.37 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.36 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.35 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.34 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.33 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.32 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.31 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.30 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.29 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
> - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12,
>     v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2,
>     v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26,
>     v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33,
>     v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5,
>     v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].

My composer.json file looks like this

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "sneek/laravel-xss-middleware": "^1.1",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^5.1",
    "usmanhalalit/laracsv": "1.*@dev",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "2.*",
    "whoops/soap": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

and I have run composer update via terminal on my local machine and the lock file seems to have updated correctly.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: what version of php you have on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your php version to at least php 7.1.3

Please see the Laravel 5.6 requirements.

Quotes from laravel page.

```
PHP
Laravel 5.6 requires PHP 7.1.3 or higher.
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0